# SwiftUI preview running in low resolution

Tags: xcode, swiftui, preview

I am testing out SwiftUI, but my Xcode preview runs in a very low resolution compared to the Simulator app, which makes it quite hard to do some "pixel-perfect" designs.

[See how it looks in this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/alAq0.png)

This happens on all zoom levels. Anybody else experiencing this?

Cheers,

Massimo

Comment: Don't you think that Preview is just a *preview*.

Comment: Well, I've seen plenty of other renderings online where it isn't _that_ bad...

Comment: I have same Preview... Live Preview has same quality as Simulator (actually it is in-site simulator).

Answer (score 0):

You can just press "Play" button.